# How to solve the differential equation $(2x^3y)\:\text{dy}+(1-y^2)(x^2y^2+y^2-1)\:\text{dx}=0$?

Tags: calculus, integration, algebra-precalculus, ordinary-differential-equations, derivatives

> Solve
>   $$(2x^3y)\:\text{dy}+(1-y^2)(x^2y^2+y^2-1)\:\text{dx}=0$$

I tried the substitution $y^2=t$ ; $2y\:\text{dy}=\text{dt}$ to get
$$(x^3)\:\text{dt}+(1-t)[(x^2+1)t-1]\:\text{dx}=0$$

However, I don't know how to proceed further.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

since
$$2x^3yy'+(1-y^2)(x^2y^2+y^2-1)=0$$
then we have
$$2x^3yy'=(y^2-1)^2+(y^2-1)x^2y^2=(y^2-1)^2+(y^2-1)x^2(y^2-1)+x^2(y^2-1)$$
so
$$x^3(y^2-1)'=(y^2-1)^2+(y^2-1)^2x^2+x^2(y^2-1)$$
let
$y^2-1=u$,then we have
$$\dfrac{du}{dx}=\left(\dfrac{1}{x}+\dfrac{1}{x^3}\right)u^2+\dfrac{u}{x}$$
this is Bernoulli equation
$$-\dfrac{d(1/u)}{dx}=\dfrac{1}{x}\cdot\dfrac{1}{u}+\dfrac{1}{x^3}+\dfrac{1}{x}$$

then It is easy solve it

Comment: Thanks a lot! You're a genius!!

Comment: You're welcom,But I don't genius..

Comment: @math110 Can you please also help me with [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1068183/how-to-solve-y2-3x43x21-for-integers) question

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it's a tough one.  There is an integrating factor
$$ \mu = \dfrac{1}{x^2 (y^2-1)^2}$$
which leads to the implicit solution
$$
{\frac {{x}^{2}  y^{2}-
  y^{2}+1}{x \left( y  ^{2}-1 \right) }}
  = c $$

but I don't know how you would find these by hand (I used Maple).

Comment: What method did you use to find the integrating factor?

Answer (score 1):

$$(x^3)dt+(1-t)[(x^2+1)t-1]dx=0$$ 
$X=\frac{1}{x^2}$
$$X\:dt-(1-t)[(1+X)t-X]\:dX=0$$
$Y=t-1$
$$X\:dY+Y[(1+X)(Y+1)-X]\:dX=0$$
$$X\frac{dY}{dX}+(1+X)Y^2+Y=0$$
This is a Bernoulli EDO. Let : $F=\frac{1}{Y}$
$$X\frac{dF}{dX}-F=X+1$$
This linear EDO is easy to solve for $F(X)$